# Having issues with Actioncable on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, sidekiq

Hello First of all as always thank you for taking the time to read my post.

What is the steps to using actioncable/ApplicationJob's on heroku as it is now on local it's working but when using on heroku it's not working i was hoping i could get some help with this.

```
2017-02-02T20:14:30.+00:00 app[web.1]: [ActionCable] [test@gmail.com]   Could not execute command from {"command"=>"message", "identifier"=>"`{\"channel\":\"RoomChannel\"}", "data"=>"\"message:
 message\""}) [NoMethodError - undefined method 'except' for "message: message":String 2017-02-02T20:14:30.+00:00 app[web.1]: Did you mean? exec]:
 /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actioncable-5.0.0.1/lib/action_cable/channel/base.rb:266:in 'block in action_signature' 
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actioncable-5.0.0.1/lib/action_cable/channel/base.rb:265:in 'tap' | /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actioncable-5.0.0.1/lib/action_cable/channel/base.rb:265:in 'action_signature' | /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actioncable-5.0.0.1/lib/action_cable/channel/base.rb:168:in 'perform_action' |
```

Update: i added in sidekiq linked up, and setup the worker in my Procfile
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -c 3 -q default, Ran the scale command to start it. restarted the heroku server in the log it said that sidekiq was active but i still get this error i now know this error is because of the
fact that active job is not picked up.

Update 2: I added in some console.logs to monitor data on localhost i get all the connect, received, data, but on heroku i do not, and i tried to pass in data so sidekiq would catch it and that part seems to catch it so came to the conclusion that actioncable perform_action/bg/message part
it's not working when pushed to heroku i hope someone knows the answer to this it would be awesome. Please let me know if you need more information.

I have a message.rb model and there i have a perform_later action

```
after_create_commit { BroadcastMessageJob.perform_later self }
```

and in the broadcast_message_job.rb

```
class BroadcastMessageJob < ApplicationJob
queue_as :default

def perform(message)
  ActionCable.server.broadcast 'room_channel', render_message(message)
end

private
def render_message(message)
  ApplicationController.renderer.render message
 end
end
```

it works on local with this setup but still not working on heroku.
What am i missing?

Thank you in advance.